# gsutil credentials error when trying to download app reviews

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I followed Google's instructions to install Python and gsutil on Windows. When I attempt to download reviews with this command line:

```
c:\gsutil>c:\python27\python gsutil cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_rev_########/reviews/reviews_package.name_2015* c:/temp/xxx
```

I get this error message:

*You are attempting to access protected data with no configured
credentials. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
and sign up for an account, and then run the "gsutil config" command
to configure gsutil to use these credentials.*

I don't have a Google Cloud Platform subscription. Do I need to pay for one to access the ratings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the account that is responsible for that app. You will have to install the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/#Quick_Start) and authenticate using :

`gcloud auth login`

Once you do that and paste the link on a browser tab using the account that hosts the app you will receive the credentials that you can pass to gcloud and they will get saved.

Then you can use the command and won't get the error.